decoding code128 barcode to string using Spire.Barcode results with an unknown error
im trying to decode 128code barcode to string using the Spire.Barcode library.
on the app the user captures a picture. then the picture is saved to the app storage.
trying to decode the barcode results with unspecified error.
im using c# maui android (.net 8.0):
private async void OnDecodeBarcodeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         var photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();
         if (photo == null)
         {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "No photo captured.", "OK");
            return;
         }

         var tempFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "photo.jpg");
         using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
         using FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempFilePath);
         await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            
         if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))
             await DisplayAlert("file exist", $"File exist", "OK");
            
         if (photo != null)
         {
             string data = Spire.Barcode.BarcodeScanner.ScanOne(tempFilePath);
             if (data.Length > 0)
             {
                await DisplayAlert("Success", $"Decoded Barcode: {data[0]}", "OK");
             }
             else
             {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No barcode found in the photo.","OK");
             }
        }
        if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))
        {
            File.Delete(tempFilePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Spire.Barcode.BarCodeFormatException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Invalid Operation: {ex.Message}");
        await DisplayAlert("Error", $"{ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"Invalid Operation: {ex.Message}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        await DisplayAlert("Error", $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }

the error is thrown at this line:
   string data =  Spire.Barcode.BarcodeScanner.ScanOne(tempFilePath);


is it throwing an exception?  What is it?  I'm not clear what "unspecified error" means

no...this is what i meant by unspeified error

AFAIK there is no way an "unspecified" exception gets thrown in C#.  Does it get caught in the final catch block?

yes. it gets caught in the final one. this is the exception I get:
System.InvalidProgramException
at MauiApp2.MainPage.OnDecodeBarcodeClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) in /Users/davidfrucht/RiderProjects/David-app/MauiApp2/MainPage.xaml.cs:line 62
line 62 is the line I mentioned on my post

then that is not "unspecified", it is a InvalidProgramException.  I suggest you contact the author of the library for more help
